# I want to add an Integer field in a transientModel, but the field is not added. Without giving me any kind of error

Tags: python, odoo-12

class MrpProductProducefiltro(models.TransientModel):
_inherit = "mrp.product.produce"

```
servicio_mp_id = fields.Integer('Tipo servicios')
```

Comment: class MrpProductProducefiltro(models.TransientModel):
    _inherit = "mrp.product.produce"

    servicio_mp_id = fields.Integer('Tipo servicios')

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.